# Package not found error on windows in python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm getting an error when I try to access files from my working directory. This is not a duplicate of @dsphoebe 's question, because the file I try to open is certainly a .docx file and for whatever reason, I can't open it.

```
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Python\\mydocs\\'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        print(file)    #prints all word docs in my folder, just like I want
```

Now when I replace that print statement with a statement that creates a docx object,

```
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Python\\mydocs\\'
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, file))
        ...
        #continuing with what I wanted to do w/ the documents...

Error: "Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file
docx.opc.exceptions.PackageNotFoundError: Package not found at 'my doc.docx'
```

Now, in that mydocs folder, my doc.docx is the proper title and it certainly is a .docx file. This certain file's title is composed of **2 words** with one space (ie. my doc.docx). But the conversion to a type 'Document' object **works** for another word doc in that same folder that is only **ONE** word!

This works:

```
    rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Python\\mydocs\\'
    doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, "Access.docx"))
    Exited with code = 0
```

But this doesn't:

```
    rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Python\\mydocs\\'
    doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, "Able2Extract Professional.docx"))
    Exited with code=1
```

So `two words.docx` wouldn't work but `oneword.docx` would. Very confusing. Anyone know how to diagnose this problem?

Comment: Does the file "my doc.docx' open if you put a hyphen where the space is? That's a useful test because it would rule out a problem with the .docx file and narrow it to an OS file opening problem.

Comment: No, my-doc.docx would not open it :( so that means it's an OS file opening problem?

Comment: **Some of the documents in my list were from BEFORE 2007- which python-docx CANNOT handle. That was my problem here** Those ones just happened to have 2 words in their titles too >:/

Comment: Yep, that will do it :) Those earlier files were of a completely different format, binary I believe. Generally one comes across those with the extension '.doc' to distinguish them from '.docx' files where the 'x' is for XML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where are you using the `rootdir` variable?

If `docx` is just trying to open 'my doc.docx' by concatenating that string with the current dir it might not be properly escaping the space character in the filename.

Try using `os.path.join()`:

```
import os.path
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\Python\\mydocs\\'
doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, "my doc.docx"))
```

Comment: I was actually using the `rootdir` for another thing to see if it was actually in the foler I wanted. here was what I was using it for: `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir): for file in files:print(file)` This listed every word doc that was in my folder. But when I replaced the `print(file)` command with a document object command like `doc = docx.Document(file)`, it would tell me that the 2-word titled document was not found. I tried the os.path.join and still the same error... @Eric La Fevers

Answer (score 2):

Eric answer is completly right, just would like to remark than I had same excpetion and the error was that I had word document already opened.

Solution: Close word document and open a copy if you want to parse and read it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message, because of an error in the path. (Missing /)